# BASH sorting file names by version

Tags: linux, bash, sorting

I need to order these file names (and I can't change them):

- file_31_stable.sql
- file_32_stable.sql
- file_310_stable.sql
- file_41_stable.sql
- file_42_stable.sql
- file_410_stable.sql

This is also the expected order that I want to display them, because I have to get the last one.

When I use the command

```
find ./databases/ -iname file_*.sql | sort -V
```

The output is this:

```
file_31_stable.sql
file_32_stable.sql
file_41_stable.sql
file_42_stable.sql
file_310_stable.sql
file_410_stable.sql
```

There is a form to order using the first number of the file and then the rest, or a command that will display the expected order?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without any separators, version 310 is obviously newer than version 41.

If you can devise a way to automatically add a separator, of course do that. Maybe

```sh
find ./databases/ -iname 'file_*.sql' |
sed 's/^\([^_]*_\)\([0-9]\)\([0-9]*\)/\2.\3\t\1\2\3/' |
sort -k1 -V |
cut -f2-
```

if you know the major version must always be a single digit; but obviously, in the general case, no such assumptions can be made.

This adds a column before the actual value, sorts on that, and then peels off the added column; see also [Schwartzian transform](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform). Before the `cut`, the output from `sort` looks like

```
3.1     file_31_stable.sql
3.2     file_32_stable.sql
3.10    file_310_stable.sql
4.1     file_41_stable.sql
4.2     file_42_stable.sql
4.10    file_410_stable.sql
```

If your `sed` does not recognize `\t` as a tab, maybe try putting a literal tab (I can't do that here because Stack Overflow renders tabs as spaces).

Comment: `sort -n` may be better than “normalizing” the numbers manually…

Comment: No, that would put 3.12 between 3.1 and 3.2